# MongoDB Update object inside Multi Nested Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a project using `NodeJS` and `MongoDB`.
I am using `mongoose` as well.
I have the following collection:

```
array1:[
    {
        field1:{type:String,default:null}
        array2:[
            {
                id:{type:String,default:null},
                field1:{type:String,default:null},
                field:{type:String,default:null}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So I want to update "field1" and "field2" inside "array2" using the "id" but I am unable to achieve this with `update` query. Can you please suggest me on how to achieve this using `update` query?

Currently to update it I used

```
document.save(function(error,response){});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i believe is to set the array2 as an array of a collection, and create a new collection for this object of array2.Doing that and having the id you can easily find it usign Collection.findById, and also it would get a better performance as you won't need to read and allocate memory for all values of array1 and array2 before finding the object you want.

Comment: Consider "array1" as "genre of songs", "array2" as "list of songs", "field1" being "title of song" and "field2" being "name of the album"... 
So as you can see I cannot or rather don't want to separate array2 as a separate collection, then it would be similar to keeping a relational DB.